# Form Sending get request instead of post

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, post

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="login_form" data-ajax="false">
     <label for="username" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username"/>
     <label for="password" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password"/>
     <button data-theme="b" id="submit" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Here is the js:

```
$('#login_form').on('submit', function (e) {
    var $this       = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    //some validation here

    if (formValid)
    {
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        $.post(loginURL, $this.serialize(), function (response) {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();  
            //response handling here
        }, 'jsonp');
    }
    return false;
});
```

So the problem is:
The form still sends the GET query.
What is wrong here?
PS: testing on ripple emulator if it matters

Comment: What did you have on loginURL? Is there has some code do redirect again? First time your request is post, maybe next time the code which was located on loginURL do redirect (is GET)